# Using Views to add number of forms together

Tags: lotus

I am creating a database for software product keys at work which means having to document every product key in notes. I want to be able to say in a column how many of these product keys are assigned and how many are not. I have assigned a basic binary value to every form which can either make it assigned or not and leads to give the form a structure such as this ( the keys are false obviously)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4QUm.png]

I want to add a line next to Office 2013 that says XX Assigned, XX Unassigned for instance and I want this to work across every possible product I add to the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that it is possible exactly as you wanted.

After "Assigned" column add a column, with 1 set as the column value (look at the picture below).

[image]

Open the second tab of the created column and set "Totals" to "Total" and check "Hide detail rows".

In this case just after "Assigned" column there will be a column with number of entries, which belong to this category.